# Software to stabilize timelapse images

Tags: software, timelapse, image-stabilization, software-recommendation

and Happy new year!

I have shooted ~300 photos of an object and i'm making timelapse from it. The distance between me and object is 5-7 meters. All these photos are made from different angles, but with the same object in the center similar to [this video](https://vimeo.com/67097843). The idea is to make turning timelapse about that object. The problem that I have is stabilization. The difference between main object on different photos can be up to 200-300px in both X and Y axis.

I've tried to achieve it with After Effects with Warp Stabilizer and Track Motion, but it didn't help too much. The main object on that video is turning from 0 to 180 degrees, and brightness of pictures is very different, so there is no too much points to track them, and AE somehow didn't work well for me. Maybe I used it in incorrect way. But is there any others way to achieve it?

P.S. Currently I achieved it by making small console application that tracks specific colors in allowed color range, as there is one sign with red color but it's small object, and then it makes shifts based on location of these colors and their count. Partially it works well for me, but I'm sure that I made another useless program as it can be achieved with other software. Is there any software that can helps me for such stabilization?

Thank you.

Comment: It's similar, but the same. Because shake is a problem for typical timelapse. But in my case photos are around object, so it's not typical shake, and it's hard to detect it

Comment: You could still try the suggested answer, might work for you as well. Also the difference in brightness might pose a problem for the tracking. Did you try fixing the exposure first such that a more or less continuous brightness is achieved across the frames? This might make After Effects tracking work better.

Comment: You may want to consider trying Photosynth from Microsoft as a way to view your images - the new version is in preview, but has a "type" of synth appropriate for how you appear to have sourced your images.  http://photosynth.net/preview

Answer (score 0):

You can do it manually I guess in Photoshop. Load up 5 consecutive images as layers, use transparency, and align the images. Then save and close the oldest image layer, open a new layer for the 6th, etc.

Then make a test video and see if there is an unwanted glitch somewhere, then repeat the alignment procedure.

Comment: well, there are 300 hundreds of them. Process them in Photoshop manually will work I suppose, but it will require much more time

Comment: Well, it may take two hours as soon as you get used to it... You can also adjust color temp, colors, perspective errors, etc.